# NSTimer not working Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I've seen this a couple of times before, but it never occured to me what might be wrong.

Firstly, I want to create the effect of scrambling numbers like they do in those hacking scenes in movies. So, I made an `NSTimer` to make my delays such that every 0.2 seconds, the numbers change. Then, I made another timer to tell my first timer to

```
invalidate()
```

after two seconds. My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class MainPage: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var genericDeviceName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var hackButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var rightNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var leftNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var detectionText: UILabel!

@IBAction func deviceNameEnter(sender: AnyObject) {
    detectionText.text = "Device detected: " + genericDeviceName.text!
    if genericDeviceName.text == "" {
        detectionText.text = "Error"
    }
    hackButton.alpha = 1
}


@IBAction func hackDevice(sender: AnyObject) {
    var tries = 0
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var timerStop = NSTimer()
    timer = NSTimer (timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timerStop = NSTimer (timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: "endTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(9) + 1)
    let diceRollSecond = Int(arc4random_uniform(9) + 1)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations:{
        self.hackButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))})

        func update() {leftNumber.text = String(diceRoll)
        rightNumber.text = String(diceRoll)
    print("it worked!")}

    func endTimer() {

    timer.invalidate()
        detectionText.text = "Access Granted!"
        timerStop.invalidate()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

So... what went wrong? The last few times I tried using `NSTimers`, they didn't work either. Is my concept of an `NSTimer` wrong? Or is there an error in my code? There was no error message triggered, it was just that the timer did not trigger and the numbers did not change. Not even "it worked!" was printed to the logs. Please help by suggesting some code. Thank you in advance!

*UPDATE*

I've updated my code. Here it is:

```
 import UIKit


 class MainPage: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet var genericDeviceName: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var hackButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var rightNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var leftNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var detectionText: UILabel!
@IBAction func deviceNameEnter(sender: AnyObject) {



    detectionText.text = "Device detected: " + genericDeviceName.text!

    if genericDeviceName.text == "" {detectionText.text = "Error"}



    hackButton.alpha = 1

}
let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(9) + 1)
    let diceRollSecond = Int(arc4random_uniform(9) + 1)

func update(timer: NSTimer) {leftNumber.text = String(diceRoll)
    rightNumber.text = String(diceRoll)
    print("it worked!")}

func endTimer(timerStop: NSTimer) {

    timer.invalidate()
    detectionText.text = "Access Granted!"
    timerStop.invalidate()}

@IBAction func hackDevice(sender: AnyObject) {




    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "update:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    var timerStop = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "endTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timerStop, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)


    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations:{
        self.hackButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))})



    }










override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

 }
```

Currently, it seems that the function "endTimer" does not work, due to the variable "timer" not being recognised. Please help. Thank you all so much for your time!

Comment: You didn't called `addTimer:forMode:`. It's clearly written in the doc of Timer method you call.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot, everyone for your efforts in solving my problem. It appears I have narrowed the bug down to the defining of the function "endTimer". It cannot recognise the variable "timer". How should this be fixed?

Comment: timer is locally scoped to hackDevice. Try declaring it outside of hackDevice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move your functions out of hackDevice. Nested functions like this are generally not used in Swift.

For example:

```
let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(9) + 1)
let diceRollSecond = Int(arc4random_uniform(9) + 1)
var timer = NSTimer()
@IBAction func hackDevice(sender: AnyObject) {

    var tries = 0
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var timerStop = NSTimer()
    timer = NSTimer (timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timerStop = NSTimer (timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: "endTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations:{
        self.hackButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))})
}

func update() {
    leftNumber.text = String(diceRoll)
    rightNumber.text = String(diceRoll)
    print("it worked!")
}

func endTimer() {
    timer.invalidate()
    detectionText.text = "Access Granted!"
    timerStop.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: Yes. I tried this before as well. I posted a similar question to this before, but I got this reply. The code works, but it gives the error "unresolved identifier "diceRoll"" and "diceRollSecond". How should I resolve this?

Comment: The problem you are facing is one of scope. Swift is a tightly scoped language. That means that variables and functions are only accessible in the code block in which they are declared, hence why calling update and endTimer after delay cause them to do nothing. They had gone out of scope. Declaring diceRoll and diceRollSecond in a function mean they are only available within that function. Declare them outside of hackDevice so they are available class-wide.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I finally solved the problem. Thank you all!

Answer (score 5):

A few things: The selector for an NSTimer should end in a colon (e.g. "update:" or "endTimer:" And the function should take a single parameter: An NSTimer.

Second, the function that the timer calls must be a top-level function of the target. Your update method is a local function of your `hackDevice`, function, which won't work.

Third, you need to use scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval, as in ShahiM's answer:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
  0.4, 
  target: self, 
  selector: "update:", 
  userInfo: nil, 
  repeats: true)
```

That code crashes if the function in your selector is a nested function because it's not visible to the timer.

Finally, it looks like you need to move the variables `diceRoll` and `diceRollSecond` out of your `hackDevice` function and make them instance variables of your class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did help resolve many errors except... when I moved the function "endTimer" out of the hackDevice function, XCode complained about how "timer" and "timerStop" were not recognised. If I move those out, how do I trigger the timer upon pressing the button?

Comment: Edit your post to show your updated code at the bottom as an update. include the variable definitions from the top of your view controller class, as well as the `hackDevice`, `update:` and `endTimer:` functions. (It sounds like you need to move "timer" and "timerStop" to top-level functions/variables as well.)

Comment: Done. Please help me to check the endTimer part. Thanks :)

Comment: Move the declaration of timer and timerStop to the top level of your class, right below the outlets. Change the name of the parameters to update() and endTimer() to be something unique, like `timerParam`. If the parameter has the same name as an instance variable it hides the instance variable, which is bad. You need to read up on variable and function scope.

Comment: can you give me some example? I tried putting everything stated below the outlets, but they gave the error argument type 'NSObject - > () -> ainPage' does not conform to expected type "AnyObject". Thanks. I'm not really a pro at coding, so thanks for your patience. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using this :

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Also move your `update` and `endTimer` methods outside the `hackDevice` method.

**Explanation :**

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/) :

> Use the `timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: or timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` class method to create the timer object **without scheduling it on a run loop**. (After creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by calling the addTimer:forMode: method of the corresponding NSRunLoop object.)

.

> Use the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: or scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: class method to **create the timer and schedule it on the current run loop** in the default mode.

So in your code, you only create the timer but it does not start running. You have to either call the `addTimer(_ timer: NSTimer,forMode mode: String)` to start the timer or you can simply use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` to launch the timer right away.

Comment: That gave me the error "Signal SigaBRT". I tried it out before, which was why I had to change it to what it currently is.

Comment: Because your `update()` is not part of the class member declaration - it is just a local function.

Comment: @MintonLee move your `update` and `endTimer` methods outside the `hackDevice` method

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't nest this kind of function, `selector` will not find them because they will be exposed after the method exit, after the function leave the last `}` there will be no a `update` and `endTiemr`
2. Your timer should look like this `let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("update:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`
   and on the other side `func update(timer: NSTimer) {`

Also try adding the timer to the run loop after initialisation:

```
    let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("update:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your update you redeclared the variable timer, this way you created a local variable which exists just in the method `hackDevice:` , remove the var before the `timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimer...`

Edit:
I rather edit this answer, because here i can add insert code snippet with proper newlines and indents:

```
class MainPage: UIViewController{
   // Your IBOutlets
   @IBOutlet var ...
   var timer= NSTimter()

   // Your methods
}
```

Comment: because you need to declare the timer outside of a method but inside the class, just like your @IBOutlets. These are properties: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html